# Is there a step I am missing in the factor conversion to create a new output?

Tags: r

So I had this already working but for some reason the character to factor conversion just "crashed" on me. Thus my question is if I am missing a step or am I off completely? I am just starting to understand it.

I have already tried different websites which none have helped me at all. I have also retried what I had originally as follows: `stretch <- c("510A", "510B", "510C", "510D", "510E", "510F", "510G")` then conversion `rivertemp_2015$strech <- as.factor(rivertemp_2015$strech)`

```r
stretch <- c("510A", "510B", "510C", "510D", "510E", "510F", "510G")

#conversion
rivertemp_2015$stretch <- as.factor(rivertemp_2015$stretch)

#OR
stretch.factor <- stretch
rivertemp_2015$stretch <- stretch.factor
```

I expected the output to be

```
Factor w/ 7 levels "510A", "510B",...: 1 1 1 1 1 1...
```

but the actual results are

```
Factor w/ 7 levels "510A", "510B",...: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

but when I want to factor I get either

```
Error in $<-.data.frame'('*tmp*', stretch, value = integer(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, and data has 10257
```

OR

```
$<-.data.frame'('*tmp*', stretch, value = ("510A", "510B",...)) : replacement has 7 rows, and data has 10257
```

Comment: Try `rivertemp_2015$stretch <- as.factor(stretch)`

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Getting the same errors again.

Comment: Why do you expect output to be `Factor w/ 7 levels "510A", "510B",...: 1 1 1 1 1 1... ` ? Those are different `factor` levels so each one of them would take an unique index.

Comment: You *probably* want something like `factor(rivertemp_2015$stretch, labels = stretch)` (assuming there are 7 distinct values in `riverbank_2015$stretch`).  You haven't really given enough information to know for sure but it seems you're trying to apply a vector of labels to an existing column of a data.frame (but it's confusing as it seems you've given both the same name).

Comment: Because that is how I was able to get it to work. But for some reason now it only gives me those errors and I used that exact same code the first time and it worked just fine.

Comment: @H1 I want to make another column named stretch where the first 4 characters are from ID. Is there a way to upload a whole file?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah. I will take a look at it again.